# I drank water in a cup

Tags: prepositional-phrases

- I mixed eggs in a bowl.

(It means I put eggs in a bowl and mixed them).

- I baked bread in an oven.

(It means I put bread in an oven and baked them).

- **I drank water in a cup**

Logically, it should mean I put water in a cup and drank it (=I drank water with a cup). But why does it sound so awkward.

Comment: Because it's not idiomatic in English - we drink **from** a cup. (In French you do 'drink in' a cup, so your idea isn't so strange.)

Comment: I drank (the) water in the cup. versus I drank water from a cup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds awkward because there are other senses of in.

> I watched a movie in the cinema  (This doesn't mean you put the movie in the cinema and watched it) ... I learnt French in France (You didn't put the language in the country and learn it)

Moreover, in your two examples, the process (of mixing, of baking) occurs *in* the bowl (or the oven).  But when you drink, the process of drinking occurs in your mouth. Or the location is your body's location, not the water's location.

So the preposition "in" isn't correct.  Instead, you drink *from* a cup.

Comment: That makes sense. Because gargling occurs in one's mouth, is it acceptable to say I gargled in my mouth?

Comment: @Faint - it might be silly if you said you gargled in your mouth (because of redundancy, like saying 'seeing with my eyes' or 'hearing with my ears') but don't most people gargle in their throat?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey LOL I don't gargle in my throat because it's itchy.

Comment: @Faint - OK you can gargle in just your mouth (I checked in a dictionary).

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is ambiguous. Consider:

I drank water in a cup.

I drank water in my kitchen.

In the second sentence, what the speaker surely means is that he was in his kitchen when he drank the water. But in the first sentence, he surely does not mean that he was in a cup when he drank the water, but rather that the water was in a cup.

You get these kind of ambiguities in language all the time. We usually figure them out based on knowledge of the real world rather than purely on grammar. Like, it's POSSIBLE that the speaker is sitting inside a giant cup drinking water out of a bottle. Or that his kitchen is flooded and he is drinking the water that fills his kitchen. But we know these things are, shall we say, unlikely, so we tend to rule them out. (There are many jokes whose humor relies on the listener making this kind of rational assumption, and then breaking this assumption.)

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to refer to the act of drinking from a particular vessel, use **from**:

> She drank wine from a goblet.
>
> Some folk sip their tea [from a saucer](https://youtu.be/0DjQB7DELJs).

If you wanted, for some particular reason, to specify what vessel contained the beverage, you could use **in**:

> The woodsman came back to his hut to find an old woman slumped over in a chair in his kitchen.  He tried to rouse her.
>
> "Wake up!" he said, shaking her by the shoulders.
>
> But she was very drowsy and her pupils were very large.
>
> "What are you doing here? he asked.
>
> "I was lost in the woods and very thirsty" she replied. "So I took a drink of the water in a cup sitting on the windowsill. I suddenly felt very dizzy and came inside as there was no one at home."
>
> "Ah, I see. That wasn't water ..."